# How to upload image saved in local device to Instagram Graph API

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

I want to post on Instagram using Facebook Graph API. To post image, it require URL of image saved in public server. Below is the python code which I am using -

def postInstagram():
post_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/my_id/media"

```
payload = {
    "image_url": image_url,
    "caption": my_caption,
    "access_token": my_token}
r = requests.post(post_url, data=payload)

result = json.loads(r.text)
if 'id' in result:
    creation_id = result['id']

    second_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/my_id/media_publish"
    second_payload = {
        "creation_id": creation_id,
        "access_token": "my_token"
    }
    r = requests.post(second_url, data=second_payload)
```

But I want to post image directly by uploading it from my local device and not by URL. I don't know how to do that. Please help me.

Comment: The documentation does not mention that this was possible, so assume it isn't.

Comment: You can use ngrok for this.

Answer (score 0):

So google search brought me here and I have a good answer for this but I assume that the OP doesn't use StackOverflow anymore as this question is years old. However for anyone else running into this issue you can use ngrok for this.

1. **Download and install ngrok**. (If you are on windows and you download ngrok just have the exe in the same directory. If you are using linux download and install ngrok from your repo using apt-get, or yum, or snap depending on your linux flavor)
2. Run **http server** and **ngrok** then your pictures will be servable to instagram.
3. Instagram will take the url and get the picture.
4. Once its done immediately close the http and ngrok server.

Here is a python example that worked for me perfectly. You MUST have ngrok installed and you MUST get your api key (user token or app token......I hate meta's token stuff. It took forever for me to understand. lol).

```
import requests
import http.server
import socketserver
import threading
import subprocess
import time
import json

# Start a simple HTTP server in a new thread
PORT = 8000
Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
thread = threading.Thread(target=httpd.serve_forever)
thread.start()

# Start ngrok
ngrok = subprocess.Popen(["ngrok", "http", str(PORT)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# Give ngrok time to start up
time.sleep(2)

# Get the public URL from ngrok
resp = requests.get("http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels")
public_url = resp.json()["tunnels"][0]["public_url"]

# Now you can use the public URL to access your local images
image_url = public_url + "/test.jpg"
print(image_url)

access_token = "ENTER_ACCESS_TOKEN"

def create_container(access_token, image_url, caption):
    url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/ENTER_INSTAGRAM_ID/media"
    payload = {
        "image_url": image_url,
        "caption": caption,
        "access_token": access_token
    }
    response = requests.post(url, params=payload)
    data = response.json()
    print(data)
    return data["id"]

def publish_photo(access_token, creation_id):
    url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/ENTER_INSTAGRAM_ID/media_publish"
    payload = {
        "creation_id": creation_id,
        "access_token": access_token
    }
    response = requests.post(url, params=payload)
    data = response.json()
    print(data)

caption = "ENTER_CAPTION"

# get_instagram_media(access_token)
creation_id = create_container(access_token, image_url, caption)
publish_photo(access_token, creation_id)

# Remember to stop ngrok and the HTTP server when you're done
ngrok.terminate()
httpd.shutdown()
```

Remember to replace test.jpg with your actual photo.

Answer (score -1):

Official documentation says URL should be a public one

Comment: Please include the documentation for your answer. Thanks!